# Python Pandas multi index merging with a combined column of data

Tags: pandas

I have two Dataframes with the same multi-index format & names. I am trying to perform a merge of the two Dataframe so that in the innermost index ('Model') the values from each Dataframe are combined but only have one 'units sold' column given that the model values in each Dataframe are unique. The code below gives me two columns one each for the left and right Dataframe. I just want one column.

```
german_cars_sold = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Tom','Jerry'], ['2022', '2023'], ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'], ['Porsche', 'Audi', 'Benz']],
                                               names=['SalesPerson', 'Year', 'Quarter', 'Model'])
columns = ['units sold']
german = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(48).reshape((len(german_cars_sold), len(columns))),
                    index=german_cars_sold, columns=columns)

US_cars_sold = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Tom','Jerry'], ['2022', '2023'], ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'], ['Telsa', 'Ford', 'Jeep']],
                                          names=['SalesPerson', 'Year', 'Quarter', 'Model'])
columns = ['units sold']
US = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(48).reshape((len(US_cars_sold), len(columns))),
                    index=US_cars_sold, columns=columns)

combined = german.merge(US, on=['SalesPerson', 'Year', 'Quarter', 'Model'], how='outer')
```

Comment: Maybe provide a smaller example for clarity and make sure to also give the exact expected output. A `merge` will necessarily give you two columns. Maybe you just want a `pd.concat([german, US])`? or an addition `german.add(US, fill_value=0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is not a `merge` but to combine the two DataFrames with a [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
combined = pd.concat([german, US]).sort_index()
```

Which could also be done with an addition ([`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)):

```
combined = german.add(US, fill_value=0).convert_dtypes()
```

Note that the two approaches will give the same output since you do not have overlapping indices. If you did, `concat` would give you two rows for the overlapping indices while `add` would give the sum of the identical indices.

Output:

```
                                  units sold
SalesPerson Year Quarter Model              
Jerry       2022 Q1      Audi             25
                         Benz             26
                         Ford             25
                         Jeep             26
                         Porsche          24
...                                      ...
Tom         2023 Q4      Benz             23
                         Ford             22
                         Jeep             23
                         Porsche          21
                         Telsa            21

[96 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `'units sold'` to the list of columns and index labels that you are merging on:

```
combined = german.merge(US, on=['SalesPerson', 'Year', 'Quarter', 'Model', 'units sold'], how='outer')
```

**Remark:**
I tested this solution with pandas version 2.0.3

If combining index levels and columns proves to be a problem, a possible solution is converting multiindex to columns and back using `.reset_index()` and `.set_index()`:

```
combined = german.reset_index().merge(US.reset_index(),\ 
on=['SalesPerson', 'Year', 'Quarter', 'Model', 'units sold'],\
 how='outer').set_index(['SalesPerson', 'Year', 'Quarter', 'Model'])
```

Comment: That doesn't work as 'units sold' is a column and the others are indices

Comment: @NovicePythoncharmer it works for me - with pandas version 2.0.3 I agree though that the concatenation proposed in the other answer is a more straightforward approach, when there is not overlap between two data frames.

Comment: @NovicePythoncharmer another option is resetting index before merging, as shown in the updated answer.